# I want to change JavaScript progress bar color based on the value

Tags: javascript

I am creating a donut chart using a calculated value from 0 to 60. Based on 4 conditions(given below) I am able to show the name but unable to change color. How to change the color based on the below conditions. 1. Value between 0 to 15, color = Red | 2. Value between 15 to 30, color = Orange | 3. Value between 30 to 45, color = Blue | 4. Value between 45 to 60, color = Green

```
function getQueryParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return "";
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var catName = "Nil";
var cat1Marks = getQueryParameterByName("c1") * 1;
var catIndex = 0;

if(cat1Marks< 0){
  cat1Marks =0;
}

if (cat1Marks > 15 && cat1Marks <= 30)
{
  catName = "Basic";
  catIndex = 1;
}
else if (cat1Marks > 30 && cat1Marks <= 45)
{
  catName = "Intermediate";
  catIndex = 2;
}
else if (cat1Marks > 45 )
{
  catIndex = 3;
  catName = "Advance";
}

if(cat1Marks> 60){
  cat1Marks = 60;
}

function drawChart() {
  var options = {
    legend: "none",
    pieHole: 0.5,
    pieSliceTextStyle: {
      color: "black",
    },

    colors: ["green", "#f9f9f9"],
    'tooltip': {
      trigger: 'none'
    }
  };
```

Thanks in advance.